How do I connect an existing db to and existing webpage using js
I am making a website for a project and currently unable to connect and do not know how to connect my existing database with my html and js code. I have tried to use various means of connections.
Whenever I try to connect a function that involves the database to a button in html nothing happens. This only applies to the html as when I run the js it can query and add to the database. I would like to not have to learn an extra language on top of js to fix this issue but if it is required IDM.
This is my code
html
I would like to implement the insertion into the database into the submit button to then add the data from the two input boxes into the database
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <title>sign up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="pg1.html"><button class="pagebt"><</button></a>
    <a href="login.html"><button class="pagebt">log in</button></a>
    <form >
        <div class="block">
            <h1>
                signUp
            </h1>
            <h2 id="username">username :</h2>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="username" >
            <h2>password :</h2>
            <input type="password" class="input" id="password">
            <div>
                <button class="intbut">submit</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="signUp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();


// Connect to the database
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./userData.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error opening database:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to the database.");
  }
});

// Create table if not exists (ensure the table exists before inserting data)
let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userData (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  userN TEXT,
  passW TEXT
)`;

db.run(sql, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error creating table:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Table created or already exists.");
  }
});

// Insert data into the table

sql = 'INSERT INTO users(userN, passW) VALUES (?, ?)';
db.run(sql, ['userN', 'passW'], function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.error("Error inserting data:", err);
} else {
    console.log(`Row inserted with ID: ${this.lastID}`);
}
});


// Query the database to retrieve all users
sql = 'SELECT * FROM userData';
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error querying database:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Users:", rows);
  }
});

// Close the database connection
db.close((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error closing the database:", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Database connection closed.");
  }
});


how about Node.js or one of the many Frameworks such as Angular, React, or Express? Running a database connection on the frontend (client side) would be wild!

Not sure I understand. What is this .js code? Is it client side code? The one that runs inclient  browser? In other words, is this code signUp.js? If yes, then you can't do that. You are trying to save things in a databse that is on the user's PC. Which, firstly, is probably not what you want (you want to have those data yourself, on your server). And more importantly, wouldn't work any way (you can't open and save files on other people PC — you have localStorage tho, in other words, big cookies, to save things on user's computer if that is you want).

But there is no way you can directly from a code that runs on your users computer, update a database that is on your server (imagine the huge security breach that would be if that was even possible). For that, you need a "backend". That is a code that runs on your server, that can read and write whatever files and DB it wants on its machine (the server), and that can communicate, through HTTP request, with the client.

That backend can be written in JS if you prefer so. With node.js. But still, only the language is the same as the JS of your client-side scripts. It doesn't run on the same computer. So you need, in both JS, to write all the coummunication code between backend and frontend (client): on the script of your webpage, you need some code to perform some HTTP request (for example with JS function fetch) on your server to ask it to do things on the DB, and some other code to receive and process the answer. And on the server, you need some code to receive those request, act on DB accordingly,

Client side SQL request would be fun: DROP DATABASE name
